Is it safe to delete csv files from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
I created these files by the into outfile “./file.csv” sql command, and when I delete them I get this error
Permission denied 

I can only delete them using sudo
, but I am worried it will cause problems or issues

If they're just the files you created with SELECT INTO OUTFILE they're not used by the system in any way, and you can freely delete them.

Thank you, I did so, and I faced no errors
